# TypeError: insert_or_replace_entity() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to store entity into azure storage table using python. But I got following error.

```
   self.table_service.insert_or_replace_entity('myDataTable', 'A100', keyVal, self.task)
TypeError: insert_or_replace_entity() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

I have provide **4 arguments** only into **insert_or_replace_entity()** function, but compiler consider five, Why? I don't understand, please someone help me.

My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import csv 
import sys

from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

class Azure:

    table_service = ''
    task = {}

    PartitionKey = ''
    RowKey = ''
    RPI_ID = ''
        PIC_ID = ''
    Date = ''
    Time = ''
        Temp = ''   


    def openAccount(self):
        self.table_service = TableService(account_name='<My account name>', account_key='<My key>')

    def createTable(self):
        self.table_service.create_table('myDataTable')

    def setEntity(self, i):
        task_i = Entity()
                task_i.PartitionKey = 'A100'
            task_i.RowKey = str(i) 
        print task_i        

        task_i.RPI_ID = 'A100'
                task_i.PIC_ID = 'P100'
                task_i.Date = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                task_i.Time = time.strftime("%I:%M")
                task_i.Temp = '22.05'

                self.task = task_i;

        def insertOrReplaceEntity(self, keyVal):
        self.table_service.insert_or_replace_entity('myDataTable', 'A100', keyVal, self.task)

data = Azure()

data.openAccount()
data.createTable()

cnt = 0

while (cnt < 10):
    data.setEntity(cnt)
        data.insertOrReplaceEntity(cnt)
    cnt = cnt + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert_or_replace_entity(table_name, entity, timeout=None)` (https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-python/ref/azure.storage.table.tableservice.html#azure.storage.table.tableservice.TableService.insert_or_replace_entity) actually has signature:

```
def insert_or_replace_entity(self, table_name, entity, timeout=None):
```

So with `self.table_service.insert_or_replace_entity('myDataTable', 'A100', keyVal, self.task)` you are actually doing something like `insert_or_replace_entity(self, 'myDataTable', 'A100', keyVal, self.task)`, hence the five arguments.